# Recursive max stack overflow error

Tags: java, recursion, stack, stack-overflow

I am trying to write a 3 input recursive program for max and min for a data structures class. I am getting a stack overflow error. I cannot tell if I am going off the end of the array, but I shouldn't be as far as my understanding goes. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
class Extrema {

    // maxArray()
    // returns the largest value in int array A
    // p is position zero, r is position length-1
    static int maxArray(int[] A, int p, int r) {
        int q;
        if (p == r) {
            return A[p];
        } else {
            q = (p + r)/2;
            return max(maxArray(A, p, q-1), maxArray(A, q+1, r));
        }
    }

    // max()
    // returns the largest value of two ints
    private static int max(int a, int b) {
        return a > b ? a : b;
    }

    // main()
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] B = {-1, 2, 6, 3, 9, 2, -3, -2, 11, 5, 7};
        System.out.println( "max = " + maxArray(B, 0, B.length-1) );  // output: max = 11
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are using a binary search method to search for the maximum value in an **unsorted** array???

Comment: Add some debug statements to test the values p and r when maxArray is called. Can p ever equal r? And more generally, why not just a simple loop over the array to find the max value?

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
if (p == r) {
    return A[p];
}
```

to

```
if (p >= r) {
    return A[p];
}
```

and note that when you call statement

```
return max(maxArray(A, p, q-1), maxArray(A, q+1, r));
```

you lose **q** element, so call

```
return max(maxArray(A, p, q), maxArray(A, q+1, r));
```

Comment: he will get no crash any more but the code would still be wrong and not find the maximum.

Comment: regarding 2.: of course his algorithm will work, it just does not make sense, but that is something different.

Answer (score 0):

Either do it non recursive since recursion really does not make any sense here:

```
static int maxArray(int[] A, int p, int r)  {
    int max = A[p];
    for (int i = p + 1; i <= r; i++) {
        if (A[i] > max)
            max = A[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Or if you insist on some kind of recursion use your code existing with just a minor change:

```
return max(maxArray(A, p, q), maxArray(A, q+1, r));
```

Note the call to the first maxArray function now gets passed `q` and not `q-1` as end index.